# Getting data from JSON surrounding with $.when

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, twitch

I have a success function and I can't figure out why I'm not getting the data. It was working when I was doing them individually and not using "when", but I'm not sure if I'm using the "jresult" variables correctly. This is twitch's api.

```
success: function(streamdata) {
    $.each(streamdata.streams, function(i, stream){

        var json1 = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/"+ stream +"";
        var json2 = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/"+ stream +"";
        var json3 = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/"+ stream +"";

        $.when(
            $.getJSON(json1),
            $.getJSON(json2),
            $.getJSON(json3)
        ).done(function(jresult1, jresult2, jresult3) {
            var channelTitle = jresult1.display_name;
            $(".bbox_content.bbox_videos .content_loader_container").remove();
            $(".bbox_content.bbox_videos").append($('<div class="bbox_item bbox_video_item"><a class="video_item stream_item" href="/stream/' + channelTitle + '" style="background-image:url();"><span class="img"><img width="100%" src="/images/movie_arrow.png"/></span><span class=\"video_time\"></span></a><div class="bbox_video_item_info"><span class="video_title">' + channelTitle + '</span><span class="video_status"></span></div></div>').hide().fadeIn(800));
        });
    });
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Each `jresult` in your `$.when().done()` is an array and the response data from each ajax call is the first element of that array

Try

```
var channelTitle = jresult1[0].display_name;
```

Comment: can change that if you use `then()` on each request and return the response in that `then()`